# Is XtraDB stable enough for production?

Tags: mysql, xtradb

Is anyone using XtraDB (a MySQL build) from Percona?

The features & benchmark data looks nice. I wondered if it's stable enough for production.

What is your experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Stable for production" is always a subjective measurement.  If you are asking if people are using it in production, then yes, they are.

A lot of the major changes are disabled by default, and you need to turn them on for them to work.  For example - innodb_fast_recovery.  This means if you find a bug, it's very easy to take a step back.

The other point to mention, is that unless you use the Barracuda row format or enable the additional rollback segments feature - Percona releases have binary compatibility with the underlying data files with a 5.0 release.  Again, if you find a bug it is very easy to take a step back.

(I'm biased, I work for Percona).

Answer (score 2):

I'm running it on a database that serves roughly 40 queries a second and have experienced no problems.  I've never run this database on InnoDB so can't compare it however.

Answer (score 2):

I found the FAQ on the website informative for this question.

http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtradb:info:faq

I think a good point to recognize is that XtraDB is binary compatibility with InnoDB. That is you can switch back to using InnoDB at anytime.

Q: What is the risk? Can it corrupt my database?
A: Although we tested it as well as we can, there is always a risk. XtraDB modifies InnoDB kernel significantly, and it is possible there are some bugs. No one has reported any crashing or corruption issues so far.